# Can Phantom Dust for Windows 10 install and run on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: games

There is a game on the Microsoft Store called Phantom Dust. Is there a way to install and play this on Ubuntu 16.04 through Wine or any other mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at winehq.

Comment: What research have you done yourself so far?

Comment: Winehq does not have it listed in the app database.

Comment: It is only downloadable through the Microsoft Store, requiring a microsoft account.  I had no luck searching for threads about accessing a microsoft account through ubuntu or installing and playing the game through wine or any other means.

Comment: Also, thank you both for commenting.

Comment: You can _create_ a Microsoft account in Ubuntu by creating a new user at Outlook.Com or Live.Com, but you will not be able to download that game from the Microsoft Store in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To access apps, games, or content from the Microsoft Store, you must run Windows; WINE will not suffice. You can, if [your PC supports virtualization](https://vitux.com/how-to-check-if-your-processor-supports-virtualization-technology/), [install a virtualization app](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Using_Ubuntu_Linux/Virtualization) and then install Windows as a Virtual OS.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it. I will see if that can done on my system.

Comment: Two new links provide more info